# How to add custom tabs to lightning navigation menu

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I would like to know whether there is an option to add custom tabs to the lightning navigation menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spring 16 release, salesforce lightning navigation customization has been supported. You can create a menu list and assign it to specified profiles.

[image]